# sudo not working - unable to stat /etc/sudoers: Permission denied

Tags: linux, unix, centos

I changed the permission of /etc accidently and not able to resolve it

```
Sudo Error
-bash-4.2$ sudo su
sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers: Permission denied
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

/etc permissions
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 0 0     7 Oct 28 12:59 bin -> usr/bin
drw-rw-rw-.  94 0 0  4096 Mar  1 09:47 etc

files under the /etc folder shows like below 
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? yum.repos.d
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? yum.conf
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? yum
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? xinetd.d
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? xdg
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? wgetrc
```

Please help me to how to restore permission and ownership

I tried to resolve it using below commands but not able to resolve it

```
apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" install --reinstall sudo
```

apt-get command not found

```
pkexec chmod 755 /etc
```

pkexec command not found

also tried to change permission using rpm

```
rpm --setperms /
```

Comment: You could use `/bin/su` instead of `sudo`, and you could also boot in rescue mode

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution. let me enumerate the steps:

1 . try this command :

```
ls -ld /etc/sudoers
```

2 . if it's not like that :

> -r--r-----  1 root  wheel  1563 11 Dec  2016 /etc/sudoers

then change rights of that file by simply use this command :

```
chmod 440 /etc/sudoers
```

3 . Relaunch your terminal and it's ok !!

Comment: I get permission denied when trying to change permission

Comment: @AlxVallejo try to change rights with sudo flag. or get in terminal with sudo right :

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to reboot your system using *Recovery mode*. Spawn a root shelle session andrestore permissions on your `/etc`. However, errors you report are not only related to `/etc` permissions, so I think there are other problems.